# why the following query does not work (You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause)?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, sql-delete

```
delete from Person p1 
where p1.id NOT IN (
    select * 
    from (select min(id) from Person p2 where p2.Email=p1.Email) p
);
```

This query works but if i remove select * it says (You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause. Why is this the case?

```
delete from Person p1 
where p1.id NOT IN (select min(id) from Person p2 where p2.Email=p1.Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support re-opening the target table of a DML statement in the `WHERE` clause. Instead of working around with a nested select, you can `join`, which makes for cleaner code:

```
delete p1
from person p1 
inner join (select email, min(id) min_id from person group by email) p2
    on p1.email = p2.email and p1.id > p2.min_id
```

Comment: but the question was not how to get it to work, but why adding the `select * from (...)` makes it work

Comment: @ysth: I (kind of) mentionned that in the answer. Basically the nested select "hides" the reference to the target table from MySQL. I don't think this works in all MySQL version (in 5.x, I guess we would get an error because the reference to `p1.email` is too deeply nested). Hence my answer, which, as far as concerns, is the right way to do it in MySQL.